# (Pretty) Print C5.0 ruleModel as a tree?

Tags: r, machine-learning

If I train a C5.0 rule model like

```
ruleModel <- C5.0(churn ~ ., data = churnTrain, rules = TRUE)
```

and I print this with `summary(ruleModel)`, I get the rules. How can I print the underlaying tree *without* re-training with

```
treeModel <- C5.0(churn ~ ., data = churnTrain, rules = FALSE)
```

(In other words, I do *not* want to use `summary(treeModel)` - it takes a rather long time to train a model in my case, and I already have a trained `ruleModel`.)

I noticed that `ruleModel` and `treeModel` are lists, but treeModel has the additional entries "Terms" and "xlevels" and also there are some differences (found out with `all.equal`) in the list entries that have the same name. Can I transform those models into each other or is there another printing way? How do I print the ruleModel as a tree?

**Bonus:** Pretty print the C5.0 object similar to what `rpart.plot` does.

Comment: try `summary` and `plot` on the `treeModel`

Comment: @Zelazny7: :-D Obviously that is the easiest choice. My question is exactly not to do this - expect that I only have the ruleModel. I'll try to clarify my question on that point.